# Laravel mix .copy in the same directory?

Tags: node.js, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-mix

So laravel mix command mix.copy seems to optimize images however, I need the images in the exact same file structure so I have images folder in public directory and I want to run mix.copy which would optimize the images and keep them in the same directory, however at this moment when I run it removes first image and throws an error:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\public\images\default.gif'

The file was there before running npm run prod

```
mix.styles([
    'resources/assets/css/bootstrap-social.css',
    'resources/assets/css/bootstrap.css',
    'resources/assets/css/dropzone.css',
    'resources/assets/css/jquery-ui.css',
    'resources/assets/css/jquery-ui.structure.css',
    'resources/assets/css/jquery-ui.theme.css',
    'resources/assets/css/nav.css'
],  'public/css/style.css');
mix.scripts([
    'resources/assets/js/pace.js',
    'resources/assets/js/jquery.js',
    'resources/assets/js/page-load.js',
    'resources/assets/js/search.js',
    'resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js',
    'resources/assets/js/dropzone.js',
    'resources/assets/js/image-upload.js',
    'resources/assets/js/jquery-ui.js',
    'resources/assets/js/googlemap.js',
],  'public/js/script.js');
mix.copy("public/images/*.*", "public/images/");
mix.browserSync('http://localhost:8000');
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: ssee my edit please

Comment: and which laravel version is this?

Comment: laravel 5.4 it is

Comment: Try `mix.copy('public/images', 'public/images')`

Comment: unfortunately same error,

Answer (score 0):

try this way..
`mix.copyDirectory('assets/img', 'public/img');` this code should work.

Comment: Where should this code be added? Why this code should work? A bit more of explanation will probably help better understanding.